# Fetch only new branches with libgit2

Tags: branch, fetch, libgit2

Is it possible to fetch only new branches with libgit2? This would mean that no `refs/remotes/<existing_branch>` would be updated, just that new `refs/remotes/<new_branch>` would be created. Not sure what should be done with `refs/heads/<new_branch>`, but it probably should also be created, correct?

Currently, the only way I see of obtaining any new-branch-fetch behavior is to call `git_remote_fetch()` with NULL for refspecs. This will however update whole repository. Or, should I call `git_remote_ls()` and create explicit refspec for `*fetch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not semantics which exist anywhere within Git, so you'd have to do it yourself. If you want to figure out which branches are new, you have to use `git_remote_ls()` before the fetch itself, figure out which are the new branches and then use a list of refspecs to download only those.

I don't know what you mean by using a `NULL` achieving this behaviour, because there's no way to set the default refspecs to do that. That will just behave like `git fetch` and use the configured refspecs for the given remote.